Is it possible to build and run an APK, to be run on stock Android which can run 24/7 on the foreground?
I am doing research to see if it's possible to use stock Android(not rooted) as a platform to run my home monitoring application. Basically my Android device will run on continuous power, designated only for running this application. This application may involve obtaining and processing camera video stream and microphone audio stream.
My concern is Google Play Service may not allow such foreground app running for 24/7, and may send such app to background and lock the screen after a period of time.
To my knowledge, such limitations existed in the past. I'm not sure current state. It will be great if someone can tell me this aspect of feasibility at the planning stage of my own project.
